# Exclude JPA Spring boot - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa' causes error in CRUDRepository when starting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My plan is having 1 code 2 different app. Only 1 app will connect to database and hava a transaction. I am having an error when starting my webapp in the application where it doesnt have any database , the only way is to exclude JPA dependencies. When starting the application , it throws an error

> Parameter 2 of constructor in chat.ChatService required a bean of type 'chat.ChatLogRepository' that could not be found.

This is my spring boot application

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ApplicationDmz implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(chat.ApplicationDmz.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    RestOperations restOperationsDmz() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

}
```

This is my service calling the CRUDRepository

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class ChatService {

  @Getter
  private SimpMessageSendingOperations template;

  SimpUserRegistry userRegistry;
  private ChatLogRepository chatLogRepository;
```

And this is my CRUDRepository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ChatLogRepository extends CrudRepository<ChatLog, Long> {

}
```

I just want to fix the issue when starting my app with exclude JPA

Comment: Your application should have an `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. If you don't want JPA you, indeed, have to exclude the dependency but you also have to make sure your service doesn't get instantiated as that is using a repo which requires JPA to be available.

Answer (score 0):

Your test bet is to import your repository bean manually:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Import(ChatLogRepository.class)
```

This should go within a `@Configuration` class or your `@SpringBootApplication` class.

Comment: Already added @Import but stil encountered issue rg.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.